# laravel htaccess force www

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess from laravel 6

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # force www ???

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and what I want is to force from non-www to www

I have tried several combinations but is not working (i get "redirected you too many times")

What I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How to force www ???

Comment: Check the network traffic in the browser... what do you see? What is the nature of the redirect? For the above to result in a redirect it would imply there is _something else_ that is redirecting you back to the domain apex (non-www)? Do you have any redirects in your code?

Comment: @DocRoot i don't see anything ... only this `The page isn’t redirecting properly` in firefox. I don't have redirect in my code. I also change the APP_URL from .env to `APP_URL=http://www.example.com` instead of `http://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

**Try Also**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Not working: I got this message on firefox `The page isn’t redirecting properly`

Comment: This is also an HTTP to HTTPS redirect which the OP has not mentioned, or used in their code.